# Physical significance of direction of rotational variables

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

When discussing rotational quantities, the direction of such vectors corresponds to the axis of rotation, and not he actual direction of rotation(for example, while we use torque in clockwise and anticlockwise sense, the direction of torque vector is actually the axis of rotation, which is perpendicular to both the force vector and the radial vector). So, what exactly is the physical significance of the direction of rotational variables? In which physical situations do we use them? Do we even need to define such quantities as vectors? Because as far as their use is concerned, their direction seems to e irrelevant, and we only require the direction of rotation.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: The direction of the vector specifies clockwise or anti-clockwise. Use the right hand rule, where the thumb points along the vector and your fingers then show the direction of rotation. Flip the vector, and you flip the direction of rotation (about the same axis naturally)

Comment: That's not my point...I am asking for the physical use of defining the direction of a vector along the axis of rotation and not the direction of rotation.

Comment: @GRrocks The standard definition of the angular momentum vector, torque vector etc., along the axis of rotation is the only constant choice which uniquely specifies the direction of rotation.

Comment: @MarkMitchison can you please elaborate?

Comment: @GRrocks Try to come up with another vector which specifies the direction of rotation and does not change in time. You will see that the normal convention is in fact the only unique, natural choice (up to the arbitrary convention of a right-handed coordinate system). Of course one does not have to specify rotational quantities as vectors at all. However, using vectors simplifies many formulae by allowing the standard vector notation and products to be used.

Comment: ok...that makes a lot of sense....upvote!!!